# How can I make this effect by using css3?

Tags: css

This is an amazing effect like PPT. Link is here :
http://udc.weibo.com/builder2011/data.html

I know single part was made by css3-animation effects but I don't know

1.how to play all these effects in a timeline?
2.how to make position change and local to whole effect?

Where can I find a tutorial like this?

Thanks cordially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually make the whole thing out of CSS3.

Keyframes is how you'd be able to time the different functions: http://www.leemunroe.com/css3-animations/

You would need something like an entire CSS3 powered page page, and then just place a window over that with overflow hidden. Use keyframe to move the page around but the window will only show a portion of it.

*Just realized, that actually happens to be exactly what they did.*